# JavaScript Date / Time Conversion

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have dates and times in a database in the following format:

2011-08-02T00:00:00-00:00

What is the easiest way to convert them to something like 8-2-2011?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = "2011-08-02T00:00:00-00:00".split('T')[0].split('-').reverse();
var month = date[0], day = date[1];

//remove 0 in the beginning if not necessary
if (+month < 10) {
    month = month.slice(1);
}
if (+day < 10) {
    day = day.slice(1);
}

//swap between the two
date[0] = day;
date[1] = month;

date.join('-');
```

Or you can use the boring `Date` way.

Comment: Cute.  But that produces 02-08-2011, not 08-02-2011.  You've switched the month and day by reversing the whole array.

Comment: For some reason Date() doesn't work in Titanium...  go figure...  Anyhow this got me on the right track.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code:

```
x=new Date("2011-08-02T00:00:00-00:00")
str=(x.getUTCMonth()+1)+"-"+x.getUTCDate()+"-"+x.getUTCFullYear()
```

Or:

```
x="2011-08-02T00:00:00-00:00"
x=/^(\d+)\-(\d+)\-(\d+)/.exec(x)
if(x){
   str=(parseInt(x[2],10)+"-"+parseInt(x[3],10)+"-"+parseInt(x[1],10))
}
```

Comment: No need to use Date.parse -- the string will work directly in the Date constructor.

Comment: Your suggestion works just fine in jsfiddle, but for some reason it's not working in Titanium Studio (for an Android app). There must be some Titanium API Date function that's messing me up.

Comment: @rogerlsmith: That's what you didn't mention, unfortunately.

Comment: @PeterO.  You're right...  It's Friday, the head isn't in full gear :)

Answer (score 0):

This format will work in the Javascript Date constructor:

```
var d = new Date("2011-08-02T00:00:00-00:00");
var month = d.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = d.getUTCDate();
var year = d.getUTCFullYear();

var output = month + "-" + day + "-" + year;
```

Comment: +1 for the right concept. Don't forget to prefix `var` though.

Answer (score 0):

one way could be to split up the date part

```
var date = "2011-08-02T00:00:00-00:00";

var dpart = (date.substr(0,10)).split("-");

var odate = parseInt(dpart[1],10)+"-"+parseInt(dpart[2],10)+"-"+dpart[0];
```